# how to use conditional to define different \begin and \end environment at compile time

Tags: environments, align, conditionals, htlatex

I just need little help on the syntax for this. I am using tex4ht, and I get an error when I use `empheq` for the `align` environment.

I want to build this TeX file both in pdflatex and htlatex. I normally use `\ifdefined\HCode` to conditionally compile things. But in this case, it is not working.

I need to conditionally use `empheq` or not depending if compiling with tex4ht or not.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\ifdefined\HCode
\begin{align*}
\else
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\fi
%
\lambda_{spiral}  &  =-0.0551\\
\lambda_{rolling}  &  =-56.5025
%
\ifdefined\HCode
\end{align*}
\else
\end{empheq}
\fi

\end{document}
```

I am trying to avoid duplicating all the equations in both environments. This below would works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}

\ifdefined\HCode
%
\begin{align*}
\lambda_{spiral}  &  =-0.0551\\
\lambda_{rolling}  &  =-56.5025
\end{align*}
%
\else
%
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
\lambda_{spiral}  &  =-0.0551\\
\lambda_{rolling}  &  =-56.5025
\end{empheq}
%
\fi

\end{document}
```

I think one is not supposed to break the environment with conditional like the first case above? May be due to how LaTeX parses the code? I'm using TeX Live 2013.

Comment: Haven't tested this but you could try: `\ifdefined\HCode
\renewenvironemnt{empheq}{\begin{align*}}{\end{align*}}
\fi`, and just use the `empheq` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grab the contents of the conditional environment using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq,environ}
\NewEnviron{pdfORht}[3][]{%
  \ifdefined\HCode %htlatex
    \begin{#3}
      \BODY
    \end{#3}
  \else% pdflatex
    \begin{#2}[#1]{#3}
      \BODY
    \end{#2}
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{pdfORht}[box=\fbox]{empheq}{align*}
  \lambda_{spiral}  &  =-0.0551 \\
  \lambda_{rolling}  &  =-56.5025
\end{pdfORht}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can fiddle with the interface yourself.