# Syntax to setup environment using environ package with multiple arguments

Tags: environments, tex4ht

I can't get the syntax right. I am trying to use this answer below to help me.

[how to use conditional to define different \begin and \end environment at compile time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168810/how-to-use-conditional-to-define-different-begin-and-end-environment-at-compil)

I am trying to setup an environment for tex4ht vs. pdflatex. If tex4ht is running, then the environment will be

```
\begin{Verbatim}
   .......
\end{Verbatim}
```

If pdflatex is running, then it will be

```
\begin{Verbatim}[samepage,fontsize=\small,frame=single]
   .......
\end{Verbatim}
```

I am not able to figure the API to `\NewEnviron` to pass those additional arguments above inside the `[....]`

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}%    
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{array}%for m option

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{X}[4][]{%  takes 4 arguments, samepage,fontsize=..,frame=...,Verbatim
  \ifdefined\HCode %htlatex
    \begin{#4}
      \BODY
    \end{#4}
  \else% pdflatex
    \begin{#4}[#1,#2,#3]  %is this right?
      \BODY
    \end{#4}
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{4in}|m{2.5in}|}\hline
\textbf{Mathematica}
\begin{X}[samepage][fontsize=\small][frame=single]{Verbatim}  %is this right?

    {(10 E^(-t/10) HeavisideTheta[t] 
       Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}   some Verbatim stuff

\end{X}
&
   some text
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The above should become the following (if pdflatex is running)

```
\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{4in}|m{2.5in}|}\hline
\textbf{Mathematica}
\begin{Verbatim}[samepage,fontsize=\small,frame=single]

   {(10 E^(-t/10) HeavisideTheta[t] 
       Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}

\end{Verbatim}
&
   some text
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

and if tex4ht if running, it should become

```
\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{4in}|m{2.5in}|}\hline
\textbf{Mathematica}
\begin{Verbatim}

    {(10 E^(-t/10) HeavisideTheta[t] 
       Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}

\end{Verbatim}
&
   some text
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I tried calling it as follows

```
\begin{X}[samepage,fontsize=\small,frame=single]{Verbatim}
```

But that did not help. I keep getting syntax error `Missing $ inserted \end{X}`
and `extra }` etc....

Also tried

```
\begin{X}[samepage],[fontsize=\small],[frame=single]{Verbatim}
```

What is the correct syntax to setup this environment? Using texlive 2013 and Miktex

Comment: You can't use `environ` for defining verbatim environments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't define verbatim environments using `\NewEnviron`, because those absorb the environment's content as an argument, so no category code changing, essential for verbatim, can be performed.

There is a much simpler way: define the environment in two different ways, rather than one environment that changes behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{array}%for m option


\ifdefined\HCode % tex4ht
  \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{X}{Verbatim}{}
\else
  \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{X}{Verbatim}{samepage,fontsize=\small,frame=single}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[c]{|m{3in}|m{1in}|}\hline
\textbf{Mathematica}
\begin{X}
    {(10 E^(-t/10) HeavisideTheta[t]
       Sin[(3 Sqrt[11] t)/10])/(3 Sqrt[11])}
\end{X}
&
some text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to have worked but when I started adding it to my main document, now I get these error `File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine`, the problem is I have no idea which line number it is coming from. I have to roll back my changes and see. `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref) removing `math shift' on input line 2222.
) Runaway argument?! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.<inserted text> \par <*> KERNEL.tex?`

Comment: @Nasser Sorry, but it's impossible to say anything sensible with so little information. Besides, `hyperref` isn't mentioned in your MWE.

Comment: This was meant as a FYI and not as anything specific. Your fix works fine in the MWE, but for some reason I am getting this error when I added the changes to my main document. Will try to find what is the problem. hyperref has nothing to do with this, I just copied the last few lines from the log. The error is `File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine` and will try to see why it shows up in my main document and not in the MWE. thanks.

Comment: fyi, I redid the changes and do not see the error any more. I must have did something wrong myself before. It is all working well now. Thank you again for your help.